# Updating or inserting SQL Server destination table data based on conditions from source table data

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update, sql-insert

I have two SQL Server tables, one is my destination table (`LocaleStringResource`), the other one is the source table (`TempResourceSunil`).

Source table has the following columns: [TempResourceSunil](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrFUm.png)

```
[ID], [LanguageId], [ResourceName], [ResourceValue], [Burmese], [Unicode]
```

and the destination table's columns are [LocaleStringResource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVmFn.png)

```
[Id], [LanguageId], [ResourceName], [ResourceValue]
```

I want to update the destination table `[ResourceValue]` based on `[ResourceName]` from the source file.

Example:

```
[ResourceName] = 'Account.AccountActivation'
```

means I want to check it have corresponding Burmese `[ResourceValue]` in `LocaleStringResource` table if it does not exist, I will take it from `TempResourceSunil` and Burmese column and insert it into `LocaleStringResource` with language `id =2`.

Same if `[ResourceValue]` for Unicode (language id = 3) does not exist for `[ResourceName] = 'Account.AccountActivation'` means I want to insert `[ResourceValue]` from `TempResourceSunil` with language `id = 3`.

Can any SQL expert help me?

Comment: Please check your tables links and your text... And also please check again the logic of your text in the example. I believe there are some ,mistakes in writing and explaining... Cheers! Also, in one moment you call it source table and destination table, then you call them source and destination files, and then you refer to them as LocaleStringResource table and TempResourceSunil table... Choose one name/alias for the text and use it. When someone is reading the text he does not see the "LocaleStringResource" name because he will not click on the link you have given at first...

Comment: Also, please do tag the database you are using ? Is it SQLServer, MYSQL, Oracle or something else...

Comment: any answer guys???

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

The description you gave isn't really fleshed out however, you want to use a Case Statement. [CASE STATEMENT INFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
A case statement can have multiple WHENs to cover multiple logic statements. You can even have one inside the other. I wouldn't really do that for this situation.
The example below is just a simple version.

If l.[ResourceValue] is null and l.[ResourceName] =  'Account.AccountActivation' then use the value of T.[Burmese] for column l.[ResourceValue]. ELSE means if no When within the case statement is true, then use this value.

Also be aware that if you are trying to use an INT value from the first table in a string column on the 2nd, you need to cast it as a varchar.

Test out your logic and case statements and see how you get on.

```
SELECT
l.[Id], 
l.[LanguageId],
l.[ResourceName], 
CASE WHEN l.[ResourceName] =  'Account.AccountActivation' and l.[ResourceValue] is null then T.[Burmese]
else l.[ResourceValue] end as [ResourceValue],
T.[ID],
T.[LanguageId],
T.[ResourceName],
T.[ResourceValue],
T.[Burmese],
T.[Unicode]
FROM  LocaleStringResource as L
LEFT JOIN TempResourceSunil t on (t.ID = L.ID) and (t.[LanguageId] = l.[LanguageId])
```